# Creating 9.3 version of geodatabase in ArcMap 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase

Under the What's new for geodatabases in ArcGIS 10 Esri talks about an optional parameter that allows you to create a 9.3 geodatabase in version 10.

I cannot find any other info.

Any help on how to get to this "optional parameter" working?

Comment: You can't create a geodatabase in ArcMap, unless you are referring to the ArcCatalog window inside of ArcMap.  Did you mean a 9.3 version of an .MXD file?

Comment: @seth- there's a GP tool that can be used to create a GDB.

Answer (score 14):

It's an optional parameter when using the [Create File GDB geoprocessing tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000pw000000.htm).

(Optional)

The ArcGIS version for the geodatabase to be created.

```
 CURRENT —Creates a geodatabase compatible with the currently installed version of ArcGIS
 10.0 —Creates a geodatabase compatible with ArcGIS version 10
 9.3 —Creates a geodatabase compatible with ArcGIS version 9.3
 9.2 —Creates a geodatabase compatible with ArcGIS version 9.2
```

Comment: yeah it's on the gp tool, NOT on the "create file gdb" context menu in catalog

Answer (score 8):

[Swingley](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/124/swingley)'s answer should be the accepted answer, but I'll offer this up as an alternative since I know this to be common: *Make a copy of an existing empty 9.3 geodatabase.*

At each ArcGIS release, I create an empty file geodatabase and empty personal geodatabase and store them on a network drive and on the USB.  Whenever I need new one, I just copy a geodatabase from my stash.

As I was writing this answer, I remembered [James Fee's blog post about the same topic](http://spatiallyadjusted.com/spatial/2006/11/21/esri-92-personal-geodatabases-in-arcgis-91.html) back in 2006.  It looks like he's actually added links for 9.3 and 10.0 geodatabases to the blog post:

http://spatiallyadjusted.com/spatial/2006/11/21/esri-92-personal-geodatabases-in-arcgis-91.html

Comment: Good call. If you've got old GDBs on hand, this is probably the easier solution. I remember James' old blog post but didn't realize he's still updating it.

Answer (score 4):

There's a geoprocessing tool with a version option:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Create_File_GDB/0017000000pw000000/

Comment: Cheers for that.