# Determining ESRI File Geodatabase release version?

Tags: arcobjects, python, arcpy, esri-geodatabase, api

Is there any method in Python, ArcObjects, or the File GDB API for determining the release version (9.3, 10.0, etc.) of a file geodatabase? There is a need to find all of our shared 10.0 version file geodatabases and convert them back to 9.3 since not everyone as at 10.0 yet.

I know that you can [create 9.3 version file geodatabases in 10.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3976/how-do-you-create-9-3-version-of-a-geodatabase-in-arcmap-10) so that part should be easy enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the IGeodatabaseRelease2 interface on a workspace to determine the version. It has the properties MajorVerison and MinorVersion. The MajorVersion is offset from the ArcGIs version by 7:

```
        Dim pGDBRelease As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IGeodatabaseRelease2 = pWorkspace
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(pGDBRelease.MajorVersion + 7 & "." & pGDBRelease.MinorVersion)
```