# How to create a 9.3 file geodatabase with ArcObjects SDK for ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, esri-geodatabase

In ArcGIS 10 I could use the Create File GDB geoprocessing tool to create a 9.3 file geodatabase or the Create Personal GDB geoprocessing tool to create a 9.3 personal geodatabase.
But I cant't find a similar method in the ArcObjects SDK for ArcGIS 10. The *IWorkspaceFactory2.Create* method seems only to create geodatabases compatible with ArcGIS 10.

Possible workarounds are:

- using the geoprocessing interface
- centrally [storing one empty 9.3 geodatabase](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3976/how-do-you-create-9-3-version-of-a-geodatabase-in-arcmap-10) and using that as 
  template geodatabase

But is there really no possibility to create a 9.3 Geodatabase with the ArcObjects SDK for ArcGIS 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the geoprocessor (*add `using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor;` and 
`using ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools;` to your class file*).

```
            //Initialize GeoProcessor
            Geoprocessor geoProcessor = new Geoprocessor();

            //Create file geodatabase 
            CreateFileGDB createFileGDB = new CreateFileGDB();
            createFileGDB.out_folder_path = @"c:\temp";
            createFileGDB.out_name = "chickens";
            createFileGDB.out_version = "9.3";

            geoProcessor.Execute(createFileGDB, null);
```

Comment: The geoprocessor functions are built on ArcObjects so it seems to me that there must be a way to do it without instantiating a GP object. I guess it doesn't matter if it works, but I am curious as to how the GP method does it.

Comment: Thanks Jay. The geoprocessor seems to be the only way to create 9.3 GDBs. I think raw ArcObjects can only handle current Versions of the geodatabases. Very strange.

Comment: I had the idea to take empty file (and personal) geodatabases of all the earlier versions and them to an assembly as an embedded resource and write a methods to handle writing them out to files.  Just haven't had the time.  But I would use something like that before I use that Geoprocessor (unless I already needed it for something else).

Comment: Jay, I also dislike that Geoprocessor and the idea of an embedded resource is interesting. In another context I use XML Workspace Documents as embedded resources.